# SQL Server 2008 SP

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables `actual` and `forecast`

**Actual**

```
  month    actual 
  6          20
  7          60
  8          70
```

and **Forecast**

```
 month        forecast
   9             50
  10             150
  11             85
```

I have to update it in same column, i.e. till the data is available it should be updated from actual table and when data is not available there it should be updated from forecast table.

```
  month      actual/forecast
   6                20
   7                60
   8                70
   9                50
  10                150
  11                85
```

Comment: You are requesting an update, but it seems to me like you want a select instead. So which is it ?

Comment: no ,, i just gave this for example. i need the table field to be updated only if the value is not available in the actual table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like the following. The Source column is only for your test purposes. I'm also assuming that you might require some year or something included in your queries if your data spans multiple years.

```
SELECT month, actual as 'actual/forecast', 'A' as Source FROM Actual
UNION
SELECT month, forecast as 'actual/forecast', 'F' As Source FROM Forecast
WHERE month NOT IN (SELECT month FROM Actual)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..But this is not i need.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
WITH T AS(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT month,actual FROM Actual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MONTH,forecast FROM Forecast)
)

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T) = 0
BEGIN
--UPDATE here forecast TABLE 
END
ELSE
--UPDATE here T table
```

Comment: I truely doubt this will help anyone, since the syntax is not valid anywhere